# peewee: Get a single model instead of SelectQuery when back-referencing a foreign key

Tags: python, foreign-keys, peewee

I am struggling a bit with back-referencing foreign keys in `peewee`.
Consider the following code:

```
import peewee as pw

db = pw.SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class Parent(pw.Model):
    name = pw.CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db


class Child(pw.Model):
    name = pw.CharField()
    parent = pw.ForeignKeyField(Parent, related_name="kid")

    class Meta:
        database = db

db.create_tables([Parent, Child])

bob = Parent.create(name="Bob")
alice = Child.create(name="Alice", parent=bob)
```

Getting access to Bob's children can be done with `bob.kid`, which would give me a `SelectQuery`. By design, however, I know that any `Parent` can only have a single `Child`. Accessing that child could then be done with `bob.kid[0]`.

I would like to be able to access a `Child` from a `Parent` by simply calling `bob.kid` and not `bob.kid[0]`. Can this be achieved *without* modifying the `Parent` class further?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add a property.

By default back-refs are `0..N`, so best represented by a select query.

---

**Example:**

```
class Parent(pw.Model):
    name = pw.CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db

    @property
    def kid(self):
        return self.children.get()


class Child(pw.Model):
    name = pw.CharField()
    parent = pw.ForeignKeyField(Parent, related_name="children")

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

---

**Tip:**

If the foreign key is really a one-to-one you could add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the foreign key.

Comment: Yes, that adding a property to Parent is indeed my current workaround. For the sake of simplicity, however, I would like to avoid changing the Parent class if I can. But I assume that there is no way of having the back-ref use a `get` rather than a `select`?

Comment: Correct, backrefs are always a query object.

Comment: All right. It makes perfect sense -- I was just hoping that I had missed some secret argument to ForeignKey. Thanks for your help and for the tip on the UNIQUE constraint!